# Not reading text data to sql table in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I followed most of the help I could find here.  I created a C# program that reads from a text file and inserts into a SQL database table.  I have no compiler errors, and no runtime errors either.  But, I'm not sure where in my code its not allowing to insert the relevant data into the table.  When I go to check my table after running this program, the table is still empty.

Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestSimpleDb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static string fileName = "c:/users/ronica singh/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/TestSimpleDb/TestSimpleDb/Sample.txt";
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            richTextBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create connection
                conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

                // Create command
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                // Open connection
                conn.Open();

                // Create table
                CreateTextTable();

                // Prepare insert command
                PrepareInsertTextFile();

                // Load text file
                ExecuteInsertTextFile(fileName);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close connection
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void CreateTextTable()
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "if exists(SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'Performance') DROP TABLE Performance";
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Performance (Empl_No NChar(10), Assgn_No NChar(10), Start_Date NChar(10), Perf_% Int)";
        }

        private void PrepareInsertTextFile()
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Performance(Empl_No, Assgn_No, Start_Date, Perf_%) VALUES (Empl_No, Assgn_No, Start_Date, Perf_%)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Empl_No", SqlDbType.NChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Assgn_No", SqlDbType.NChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Start_Date", SqlDbType.NChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Perf_%", SqlDbType.NChar);
        }

        private void ExecuteInsertTextFile(string fileName)
        {
            //GetTextFile(fileName);
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] columns = allLines[i].Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (i == 8 || i == 67 || i == 117 || i == 126 || i == 185 || i == 194 || i == 195 || i == 201 || i == 210 || i == 269 || i == 291 || i == 292 ||
                    i == 328 || i == 387 || i == 406 || i == 407 || i == 446 || i == 505 || i == 517 || i == 518 || i == 550 || i == 551 || i == 564 || i == 623 ||
                    i == 625 || i == 626 || i == 663 || i == 664 || i == 682 || i == 741 || i == 783 || i == 784 || i == 800 || i == 838 || i == 839 || i == 859 ||
                    i == 895 || i == 896 || i == 918 || i == 977 || i == 1025 || i == 1026 || i == 1036 || i == 1095 || i == 1117 || i == 1118 || i == 1154 || i == 1213)
                {
                     if (columns[5] == "S")
                     {
                         cmd.Parameters["@Empl_No"].Value = columns[0];
                         cmd.Parameters["@Assgn_No"].Value = columns[4];
                         cmd.Parameters["@Start_Date"].Value = columns[9];
                         cmd.Parameters["@Perf_%"].Value = columns[16];
                     }
                     else if (columns[1] == "T")
                     {
                         cmd.Parameters["@Empl_No"].Value = columns[0];
                         cmd.Parameters["@Start_Date"].Value = columns[5];
                         cmd.Parameters["@Perf_%"].Value = columns[10];
                     }
                 }
                 else if ((i > 8 && i < 59) || (i > 67 && i < 117) || (i > 126 && i < 177) || (i > 185 && i < 194) || (i > 195 && i < 201) || (i > 210 && i < 261) || (i > 269 && i < 291) ||
                    (i > 292 && i < 320) || (i > 328 && i < 379) || (i > 387 && i < 406) || (i > 407 && i < 438) || (i > 446 && i < 497) || (i > 505 && i < 517) || (i > 518 && i < 550) ||
                    (i > 551 && i < 556) || (i > 564 && i < 615) || (i > 623 && i < 625) || (i > 626 && i < 663) || (i > 664 && i < 674) || (i > 682 && i < 733) || (i > 741 && i < 783) ||
                    (i > 784 && i < 792) || (i > 800 && i < 838) || (i > 839 && i < 851) || (i > 859 && i < 895) || (i > 896 && i < 909) || (i > 918 && i < 969) || (i > 997 && i < 1025) ||
                    (i > 1026 && i < 1028) || (i > 1036 && i < 1087) || (i > 1095 && i < 1117) || (i > 1118 && i < 1146) || (i > 1154 && i < 1205) || (i > 1213 && i < 1264))
                 {
                     cmd.Parameters["@Assgn_No"].Value = columns[3];
                     cmd.Parameters["@Start_Date"].Value = columns[8];
                     cmd.Parameters["@Perf_%"].Value = columns[15];
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Anyone can help me with why I'm not seeing anything getting inserted on my database table.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no command that execute your INSERT query; study on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You never actually execute the query.  Also, the query parameters need a `@` in front of them.